# VueJS Json file with Api

Tags: javascript, json, api, vue.js, vue-component

I have a json value like

```js
{
"T1" : "online",
"T2" : "offline"
}
```

And there is an online API which send me just

```js
{
StatusCode :"T1"
}
```

I need a way to get the code from API then compare it with my local json file and print the value in input field ( not drop-down )

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. What does _"compare it with my local json file"_ mean? What _value_ are you wanting to display?

Comment: If the API send me "T1" for example I need to take it and get it's value from my local.json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not very clear but if I understand correct you want to get the value from the first object depending on the status code you get from the api. In this case you need to:

Turn the json into an object, use JSON.parse()

```
let a = {"T1": "online", "T2": "offline"};
let b = {StatusCode: "T1"};
```

you will be able to access the variable like so:

```
a[b.StatusCode];
```